# Proper way of MVC pattern when passing data to View?

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller

I'm currently reading up on proper MVC, and I'm refactoring some code of my current project. It's written in Laravel. I'll have simplified the problem to this:

I have a domain object 'User' and 'Log'. A User has many Logs.

User domain object:

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements UserInterface
    {

    protected $fillable = ['surname', 'name','email'];
    protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function logs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Log');
    }
}
```

Log domain object:

```
 class Log extends Model implements LogInterface
    {
      public $timestamps = false;
      protected $fillable = [
        'log_date',
        'log_hours', 
        'log_minutes'
      ];

      protected $dates = ['log_date'];

      public function user()
        {
          return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
        }
  }
```

In my view, I want to display the total hours logged of a certain day. I'm currently injecting a class in my controller which has a method calcHoursPerDay($user_id) which injects the LogRepository to get the Logs of that user on a given date and return the calculated value to the view.

Reading up on proper MVC, I'm inclined to drop the class and create a method for my User domain object called HoursOnDay($date). So keeping the bussiness logic in the Model.

Is this the way of using MVC, and if not, what would the proper approach?

Comment: if y answer was helpful, please upvote and choose it as best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's the proper way to do things in Laravel and MVC. `calcHoursPerDay()` should be part of User or Log model. Also, look at scopes doc, I guess that's what you want to use:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#query-scopes